# Как прописать условие внутреннего соединения чтобы записи с NULL значениями не отсекались

Tags: sql

Поясню на примере
Есть запрос:

```
SELECT T1.num, T2.id
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
on  (T1.prop1 = T2.prop1)
and (T1.prop2 = T2.prop2)
........................
and (T1.propN = T2.propN)
```

если все поля **prop1...propN** не NULL то запрос вытягивает нужные данные,
т.е. берет все строки у которых все поля prop совпадают.

но если в полях **prop1...propN** есть NULL значения, то такие строки отсекаются, как я понимаю NULL=NULL дает UNKNOWN и они не присоединяются.

Как это обойти? Что бы строки со свойствами, например

```
 prop1  prop2  prop3
```

T1: 45    NULL   67 
  T2: 45    NULL   67

присоединились.

З.Ы.: Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что `LEFT JOIN` или там `RIGHT JOIN` не работают что ли?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

and ([coalesce](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html)(T1.prop2, 999) = coalesce(T2.prop2, 999))

В случае, если столбец целочисленный, и значения 999 нет в таблице.

Comment: в данном случае строки у одной из которых NULL, а у другой случайным образом 999, посчитаются равными, хотя на самом деле этот не так

Comment: А я что написал? Такого значения быть не должно. Некое фиктивное значение. Я же не могу его придумать, т.к. не знаю, что может быть в таблицах, но не думаю, что это проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, да это как вариант, работает, только больше на костыли похоже, неужели нет какого-то другого способа, я имел ввиду то, что если поле целого типа то там может быть любое число из допустимого диапазона от ситуации случайного равенства спасет только указание второго параметра в функции coalesce() какого-нибудь другого типа, например строки, это совсем не красиво

Comment: Не нравится, пишите так, кто ж мешает:

(T1.prop2 = T2.prop2 OR (T1.prop2 IS NULL AND T2.prop2 IS NULL))

Comment: делайте не INNER JOIN, а FULL JOIN. Получите то, что вам надо.